# VS Code plugin to expand/preview constant data

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a library of mock data that might look like this:

```
// leafData.js

const emptyFoo = {
    fooData: null; 
}

const typeAFoo = {
    fooData: "typeA"
}

const typeBFoo = {
    fooData: "typeB"
}


//middleData.js 

const emptyMiddle = {
    foos: []
}

const typeAMiddles = {
    foos: [typeAFoo, typeAFoo]
}

const mixedMiddles = {
    foos: [typeAFoo, typeBFoo]
}


//rootData.js 

const scenarioA = {
    middle: emptyMiddle; 
}

const scenarioB = {
    middle: typeAMiddles; 
}
```

The idea being that tests in different parts of the codebase need to use different types of mock data.

For example there might be a component that only uses `leafData` and so those different mock types in `leafData.js` can be used there. Whereas there might be another component that only uses `middleData` so wants to use those.

The problem I have with the code structured this way is that it's actually hard to see the shape of the data when using that root data.

What I would like to be able to do is see that data in `rootData.js` as

```
const scenarioA = {
    middle: {
         foos: []
    }
}
```

while keeping the code itself as referencing the data in the other files.

Is there a VSCode plugin that will do this for me?